# Call variable by string in other module

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user form allowing users for option. The options should be saved until the excel file is closed. Before that, the options will be recorded even the user form is closed. In the user form, I have 11 checkboxes.

So I put 11 global variables under "sheet1"(renamed to DataBase) module:

```
Public chk1Last As Boolean
Public chk2Last As Boolean
Public chk3Last As Boolean
Public chk4Last As Boolean
Public chk5Last As Boolean
Public chk6Last As Boolean
Public chk7Last As Boolean
Public chk8Last As Boolean
Public chk9Last As Boolean
Public chk10Last As Boolean
Public chk11Last As Boolean
```

And I use the following code in a class to record the checkbox status to the global variable under sheet1(renamed to DataBase):

```
Private Sub Chk_Change()
    Select Case Chk.Name
        Case "chk1"
            DataBase.chk1Last = Chk
        Case "chk2"
            DataBase.chk2Last = Chk
        Case "chk3"
            DataBase.chk3Last = Chk
        Case "chk4"
            DataBase.chk4Last = Chk
        Case "chk5"
            DataBase.chk5Last = Chk
        Case "chk6"
            DataBase.chk6Last = Chk
        Case "chk7"
            DataBase.chk7Last = Chk
        Case "chk8"
            DataBase.chk8Last = Chk
        Case "chk9"
            DataBase.chk9Last = Chk
        Case "chk10"
            DataBase.chk10Last = Chk
        Case "chk11"
            DataBase.chk11Last = Chk
    End Select
    'Do other things beneath'
```

And in the main module, I use the following code to initialize the user form", if the user form is first loaded, all checkboxes will be enabled, if not, the checkboxes will follow the lase status:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    If Not DataBase.Activated Then
        For i = 1 To 11
            Controls("chk" & i) = True
        Next i
    Else
        chk1 = DataBase.chk1Last
        chk2 = DataBase.chk2Last
        chk3 = DataBase.chk3Last
        chk4 = DataBase.chk4Last
        chk5 = DataBase.chk5Last
        chk6 = DataBase.chk6Last
        chk7 = DataBase.chk7Last
        chk8 = DataBase.chk8Last
        chk9 = DataBase.chk9Last
        chk10 = DataBase.chk10Last
        chk11 = DataBase.chk11Last
    End If
    'Do other things beneath'
```

What I am trying to do is to simplify the code under class module something like below:

In sheet1(renamed to DataBase):

```
    Controls("DataBase." & Chk.name & "Last") = Chk
```

And under main to simplify the code with for loop and controls() something like below:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    If Not DataBase.Activated Then
        For i = 1 To 11
            Controls("chk" & i) = True
        Next i
    Else
        For i = 1 to 11
            Controls("chk" & i) = Controls("DataBase.chk" & i & "Last")
        Next i
    End If
    'Do other things beneath'
```

But it failed, what is the correct syntax if I want to call the variable in other modules by controls()?

Thank you very much for all of your sincere help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Public chk1Last As Boolean
Public chk2Last As Boolean
'etc etc
```

use:

```
Public ChkLast(1 to 11) As Boolean
```

Then you can address the values in the same loop as you do for the controls.

You cannot build a string to address a public variable by name. You can do certain things such as using `CallByName()` if your variables are properties in an instance of a class, but for cases such as yours an array makes more sense and avoids the extra complications.

Comment: Dear Tim, thank you very much for your reply. However, I put the global variable in worksheet module, Array is not allowed.

Comment: You can use a regular module, or write Get/Set methods in your sheet module and switch the array to Private

Comment: Thank you very much, Tim. I was late for replying. I finally move the variables to standard module and make all to be global.